# How to make Gitlab build the commit only once?

Tags: git, deployment, gitlab

I have configured my git repo so that a generated tag is added to each commit to see which build is running where as it's then added to the compiled app.

Now I see that Gitlab tries to process the commit as if it were two branches. How can I make it ignore one and build the other one (e.g. the one with the tag) as it's the same?

[image: dupe build]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set up artifacts and caching to significantly speed up the build. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/builds/artifacts.html and https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache.

As far as I know, Gitlab cannot skip duplicate build. Keep in mind, there may be different configuration for different branches, so it is not really that easy to do in general way. You should post feature request to [Gitlab issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues).

Possible workaround for this can be to create file in a cached directory and check its existence in later build. It is ugly and not 100% bulletproof, but it could do the trick.

Also, you may simply disable (some) builds for the other branch. Depends on your situation.